# CSS calc width and height values

Tags: html, css

How can I calc, using css, the screen height and use the returned value for the width calculation?
is it possible at all?

```
myClass{    
    height: calc(50% - 33.5px);
    width: heightReturnedValue*1.3
}
```

Comment: Give more info. what you want? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in css there is a thing called vh (viewport height) and vw (viewport width). The viewport is the screen.

```
myClass {    
  height: calc(50% - 33.5px);
  width:  calc(100vh * 1.3);
}
```

Comment: `vw` cannot be used the way you are using it. Did you even try that? Did you mean `0.5vh`? .

Comment: @torazaburo I updated the answer as I've seen some of my mistakes. Do you think the now updated version would work?

Comment: So what is the correct way? why is there a need to reduce 33.5px? I saw it in other places as well, is there a reason for it?

Comment: @KBE You said that you wanted the returned value of the calc() operation in height. So heightReturnedValue = 0.5vh - 33.5px

Comment: What I need is to dynamically set the width according to the screen height.

Comment: @KBE Ah, so you want heightReturnedValue = screenHeight? Then just use vh without subtracting anything. I made an edit to the initial answer.

Comment: vh es windows size no element like %

Comment: @HugoStivenLagunaRueda So where is the problem?

Comment: in your question, you used the height height result of your calc, that is, the height of the element, to calculate the width, while vh is a measure proportional to the size of the scanned window or in the case of a phone the size of your resolution. 100vh is equal to 100% of the window.

Comment: If you want to use `vh`, like any other CSS unit, it needs a **value**, like `1vh` or `50vh`. However, I don't think that is the solution here anyway.

Comment: @torazaburo You are right with one thing, that I forgot the value to vh. My intention was to write 100vh. But on the other hand, that is obviously the right solution if my answer is marked as correct.

Answer (score 1):

on CSS, It is not even possible, on javascript you would not have any problem, I would recommend the use of other varial values ​​such as `width: 100vw` relative of width of the window, `height:100vh` relative of height of window,  `max-width: & min-width:` and `max-height: & min-height:` with `width:50%` or `height:50%` your element is auto resize and have limits. You can also take advantage of elements such as the `::after` and `::before` that are relative to the father and get for example borders triangulars.

If you would put more information we could find the exact code for your problem.

method to do it with javascript can be like this

```js
 // onresize event for responsive
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].onresize=function(){
  
  element = document.getElementById("you_element");
  element.style.height = 'calc(50% - 33.5px)';
  calculateHeight = parseInt(element.clientHeight) * 1.3 
  element.style.width = calculateHeight + 'px'
  
  document.getElementById("width").innerHTML = calculateHeight;
  document.getElementById("height").innerHTML = element.clientHeight;
}
 
  
 // onload page for one set
 document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].onload=function(){
   
   element = document.getElementById("you_element");
   element.style.height = 'calc(50% - 33.5px)';
   calculateHeight = parseInt(element.clientHeight) * 1.3 
   element.style.width = calculateHeight + 'px'
  
   document.getElementById("width").innerHTML = calculateHeight;
   document.getElementById("height").innerHTML = element.clientHeight;
}
```

```css
.myclass{
       background-color:#e1e1e1
}
```

```html
<div style="width:400px; height: 500px;background-color:#f1f1f1">

<div id="you_element" class="myclass">
<p id="height"></p>
<p id="width"></p>
</div>
</div>
```